# CSS Grid achieve wrapping like flex wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I currently have this example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  gap: 5px;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Orange</span>
  <span>Purple</span>
  <span>Aquamarine</span>
  <span>Black</span>
  <span>Brown</span>
  <span>Red</span>
</div>
```

The good thing is that I have a grid that can contains a flexible number of elements and these elements are able to wrap.
The bad thing is that I have to set a **fixed** min value (here `50px` to show the problem) in order to make the items wrap.

Is there a way to achieve the same layout but without setting a fixed minimum size ? (like `flex: wrap;`).
I would love to be able to do something like this: `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 1fr))` but this is not valid CSS.

Comment: and let's suppose "auto" is valid how you want the browser to interpret it?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use a grid if a flexbox does exactly what you need?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I suppose like a flex wrap would.

Comment: @BrettDonald Because when flex items wrap, their size are independant to each other. In a grid layout, each grid cell have the same size